# How to display all tablix columns, including zero

Tags: ssrs-2008, zero, ssrs-tablix

I am developing an SSRS 2008 tablix.  The problem that I have though is that I need to display all 12 months of the year.  Currently, it only displays columns with values > 0.  Even though I entered this expression for that field:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!NumActionPlanRemainOverdue.Value)=0, 0, Sum(Fields!NumActionPlanRemainOverdue.Value))
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, a Tablix does not hide non-positive rows. Can you verify that the dataset is returning **a row for every month**?

Some additional considerations are:

- Are you showing the data in a Tablix or a chart?
- What data type is the month column?

Comment: Thanks, Cam!  No, the dataset is not returning a row for every month.  I tried to union another table with all 12 months.  But since I just unioned on this one column, this gave me an error since I dummied up the other columns in this temp table.  This is a tablix; not a chart.  Data type of month is varchar.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I think there are 2 things you can do:
1. Write the query so that it returns data for every month.
2. Sort the data according to the month.

The Tablix should display fine after that.

Comment: @CamL Is that either 1 either 2 or both 1 and 2?